# Simple script to delete old user profiles

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am writing a simple script that will be used to delete user profiles older than 90 days. I can capture the profiles that I want but, when it comes to the "bread and butter" I am stumped.

My code:

```
$localuserprofiles = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Select-Object localPath,@{Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime)};Label="LastUseTime"}| Where{$_.LocalPath -notlike "*$env:SystemRoot*"} #Captures local user profiles and their last used date
$unusedday = 90 # Sets the unused prifile time threshold
$excludeduserpath = $excludeduser.LocalPath # Excludes the DeltaPC user account
$profilestodelete = $LocalUserProfiles | where-object{$_.lastusetime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-$unusedday) -and $_.Localpath -notlike "*$excludeduserpath*"} #Captures list of user accounts to be deleted

#Deletes unused Profiles

Foreach($deletedprofile in $profilestodelete)
    {
        $deletedprofile.Delete()
    }
```

The code returns this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] does not contain a method named 'Delete'. 
At line:3 char:13 
+ $deletedprofile.Delete()} 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (Delete:String) [], RuntimeException 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: What happens/doesn't happen?

Comment: Doesn't delete, gives this error :
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] does not contain a method named 'Delete'.
At line:3 char:13
+             $deletedprofile.Delete()}
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Delete:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're getting WMI Objects, you can use the `Remove-WMIObject` cmdlet.

So, simply modifying the deletion loop like this should remove the desired profiles correctly and completely:

```
Foreach($deletedprofile in $profilestodelete)
    {
        Remove-WMIObject $deletedprofile
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not defined any `Delete()` method on a custom object `$deletedprofile`. Use

```
Foreach($deletedprofile in $profilestodelete)
    {
        $aux = Get-Item $deletedprofile.localPath
        $aux.Delete()
    }
```

or simply

```
Foreach($deletedprofile in $profilestodelete)
    {
        (Get-Item $deletedprofile.localPath).Delete()
    }
```

You may need to specify `.Delete($true)`:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Item  $profilestodelete[0].localPath | Get-Member -Name Delete


   TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Name   MemberType Definition
----   ---------- ----------
Delete Method     void Delete(), void Delete(bool recursive)
```

**Edit**

As [Mark Wragg mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43679260/3439404), one can't recommend simply deleting the user profile directory as this doesn't remove the data associated with the profile from the registry. See also an exhaustive article [**Deleting a Local User Profile - Not as easy as one Might Assume**](https://www.sepago.com/blog/2008/10/16/deleting-a-local-user-profile-not-as-easy-as-one-might-assume) by Helge Klein (author of the [`delprof2` tool](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/)).

However, there is a pure PowerShell script containing *a function (*`Remove-UserProfile`*) which is used to remove user profiles, and additional contents of the C:\Users directory (if specified) on a local computer* at `gallery.technet.microsoft.com`:
[**`Remove-UserProfile` - Remove Local User Profiles and Clean C:\Users Directory**](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-UserProfile-Remove-96e27a3b)

Comment: This method uses the `Get-Item` cmdlet to return a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object representing the directory of the profile. That PowerShell object has a delete method, which removes the directory and it's files, however beware this is not a good way to remove user profiles as it leaves behind a lot of other data and will cause those users issues logging on in the future. See my answer for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

Per the other answer, there is no `Delete()` method for user profiles provided by WMI. While you could just delete the profile directory, that's generally not recommended as you leave behind various other bits of data (such as registry entries) and can cause those users logon issues if they subsequently re-logon to the machine.

There is a free 3rd party tool called delprof2.exe: https://www.sepago.com/blog/2011/05/01/new-free-delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool

I haven't personally used this so use with care, but it seemingly already has an option to delete profiles that have been inactive for x days, e.g:

```
Delprof2 /d:90
```

> Now, what happens if you simply delete the user profile directory
>   below C:\Users without modifying the registry? The next time the user
>   logs on Windows displays a balloon tip whining that Windows could not
>   load the user profile and that the user was logged on with a temporary
>   profile. Is that bad? Yes! Temporary profiles are a last resort if
>   Windows cannot load the user profile. Upon logoff they are deleted and
>   all data is lost. That certainly is a reason to avoid them.
>
> - https://www.sepago.com/blog/2011/05/01/new-free-delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool